# Call a function, that is within a function, within a function

Tags: javascript

I have a script like this (JS)

```
function Quick () {
   this.getById = function (id) {
      return document.getElementById(id);
   }
   this.doSomethingElse = function () {
      return Quick.getById('test').nodeName;
   }
}
```

**How can I call .getById() within the same function 'Quick' (within another this.x function)?**

From the outside I would call it like this

```
var x = new Quick();
x.getById('someid');
```

but don't think I should declare a new instance of a function within the same function.

Comment: your code is fine, other than not using valid function syntax. "this.getById" > "this.getById=function". it's almost ES6, so you're just ahead of your time...

Comment: This is not valid javascript. You should either be using `this.getById = function(id) {...};` or defining `getById` in `Quick.prototype`.

Comment: @dandavis Yes I accidently forgot that in the question but in my code it's valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/biveri/1/edit?js,console)**

```
function Quick () {
   this.getById = function(id) {         // use:  = function(id) {
      return document.getElementById(id);       
   };
   this.doSomethingElse = function(id) { // pass the desired 'id' argument and 
      return this.getById(id).nodeName;  // Use the this reference
   };
}
```

IF you're interested in **chainability** [and want to do something like:](http://jsbin.com/biveri/2/edit?js,console)

```
x.getById('test').getNodeName();
// Get this ^^ guy and do this ^^
```

**what you can do is:**

```
function Quick () {

   var el; // internal variable

   this.getById = function(id) {
      el = document.getElementById(id);
      return this; // To keep your Methods chainable
   };
   this.getNodeName = function() {
      console.log( el.nodeName );
      return this; // To keep your Methods chainable
   };
}


var x = new Quick();
x.getById('test').getNodeName(); // "DIV"
```

Answer (score 0):

Module pattern would be a better fit for your requirement

```
var Quick = {
    getById: function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
    },
    doSomethingElse: function () {
    return Quick.getById('test').nodeName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the main difference between these two?

Comment: That ought to be this.getById() instead.

Comment: its about static/singleton access. If you just shared only the functionality then there is no need to "new" it.